# how to compare one column with another column of a file in unix?

Tags: text-processing

Q1. I have a file called `file1.txt` and it have 4 columns like date, filename, space and count.

ex:

```
Date  Filename      space count
nov4  abc_20161104  3.2M  1220
nov3  xyz_20161103  2.3M  2679
nov4  mnp_20161104  0.9M   234
```

I want the output on that day like below

```
Nov4 abc_20161104 3.2M 1220
Nov4 mnp_20161104 0.9M 234
```

Comment: Only  one question per post, please!

Comment: You can solve both of these questions with the `grep` command. But you should first split this into 2 separate questions. Adding more explanation and you efforts so far is also recommended.

Comment: you want only today's date lines ?

Answer (score 0):

this will grep the today's date lines in file1.txt

```
grep "$(date +%Y%m%d)" file1.txt
```

Comment: Given the sample in the original post this won't match anything. (To begin with, the dates in the sample don't contain year.)

Comment: It has... abc_20161104 ( second column)

Comment: oh, you're right, I just heeded the first column.